# How to insert multiple rows based on criteria in Column from the top of table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that has already inserted a Table (A3:L3), and filtered Column C's Value: Largest to smallest.

I would like to insert a If / Then Function.
If the Value in Column C <= to 1, insert 3 Rows below that cell.

But, I only need the formula to insert for the first occurrence starting from the top. To separate the Values >=1 (3 Rows) <=1

(The Table Columns will always be A3:L3, but end data will be unknown)

Example:
32.6
10.2
7.5
4.7
3.1
2.0
1.6
1.1
...-> Insert 3 Rows here
0.8
0.7

I currently have:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Report1")
    ws.Activate

    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value <= 1 Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(3, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Exit For
    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the range qualifier on your action statement.

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value <= 1 Then
        ws.Cells(i, 4).Offset(1).Resize(3).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The ws.cells line is showing: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error